# Is it possible to automatically hook up events in C# using VS2008?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, events

I recently switched over to C# from vb.NET and within visual studio found that hooking up events is extremely annoying.  In VB I could select a control from a drop down on the top left and the event on the top right drop down and the method would automatically be created and attached to the control using "handles".  I know that is not supported in C# but it seems I have to go through each control and add the events manually on the page and the codebehind.  Is there an easier/faster way to do this like in VB or is it just how it is?  Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is! Click a control in Design view, then click on the "Events" button in the Properties window (see 1 in hand-annotated diagram below).

From here you can see a list of all the events available to that control. By typing a method name (see 2) and pressing enter, Visual Studio will create a method (if it doesn't already exist) and hook it up properly.

Alternatively, double-clicking in the field where you would type in the handler name causes Visual Studio to assign a default value.

[image]

Comment: Nice!  Thanks, that will save me a lot of time!

Comment: And if you double-click in the field where you would type in the handler name, Visual Studio assigns a default value.

Answer (score 3):

You can setup events extremely fast in C# compared to VB. In the code window type the name of the instance and then event name then write += and press tab twice. That will hook up the event and create a method name accordingly that will handle the event.

For example write:

```
panel1.MouseClick +=
```

and then press tab once to insert the eventhandler and twice to both insert eventhandler and create the method for it.

[alt text http://img136.imageshack.us/img136/7514/eventhandlercsharp.png](http://img136.imageshack.us/img136/7514/eventhandlercsharp.png)

Comment: I always forget this one, and its one of the best shortcuts.